# Let's Encrypt Renew failed as using Varnish on Port 80

Tags: magento2

Site running well with Varnish. And varnish running on port 80. But when ssl renew is forced it showing error.

```
Attempting to renew cert (ekafela.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/exmple.com.conf produced an unexpected error:
Failed authorization procedure. exmple (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://devenv.exmple.com/.well-known/acme-......
```

As because 80 port is used by varnish and it's redirect to 404 page with the request URL, now any idea how to resolved this?

Comment: SSL port is 443. You can't serve HTTPS requests with Varnish. Varnish can only deliver HTTP content. What I am usually doing is run Apache on 8080 and then Varnish 80 and Nginx on 443.

Comment: You can refer to this to fix the same -
https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/hitch-letsencrypt/